How to make escaped braces \{ and \} recognized as delimiters in latex-mode
In latex-mode in Emacs, I want to configure the syntax table such that only escaped braces \{ and \} are recognized as delimiters for expressions (sexp), while unescaped braces { and } are treated as regular characters.
Currently, latex-mode treats { and } as delimiters, but I need this behavior specifically for the escaped versions \{ and \}.
Here is a MWE of LaTeX code to illustrate the issue:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Here is some text with \{escaped braces\} and {unescaped braces}.
\end{document}

(with-syntax-table (copy-syntax-table latex-mode-syntax-table)
  ;; Treat { and } as regular characters
  (modify-syntax-entry ?{ "_" latex-mode-syntax-table)
  (modify-syntax-entry ?} "_" latex-mode-syntax-table)
  ;; What should be added here to make \{ and \} recognized as delimiters?

  ;; BODY

)

Is there a way to modify the syntax table or use another method to achieve this behavior? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
